# Aggregate function(sum) in SQL based on time periods

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, aggregate, netezza

I am trying to apply the sum function to a column using a specific where condition. The table contains minutely data for one year. I want to aggregate using where condition such as Datetime > 06/11/2018 10:10:00 and Datetime <= 06/12/2018 10:10:00.

Below is the data:

```
 PL          Datetime
-595.70000   2017-12-13 10:10:00 
680.000000   2017-12-13 10:11:00
-400.00000   2017-12-13 10:12:00 
550.000000   2017-12-13 10:13:00 
-164.30000   2017-12-13 10:14:00 
-74.400000   2017-12-14 10:15:00 
74.4000000   2017-12-14 10:16:00 
365.000000   2017-12-14 10:17:00 
464.300000   2017-12-14 10:18:00 
715.700000   2017-12-14 10:19:00
```

Pardon me if I didnt get the correct format in writing the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: So, add a `where` clause to your aggregation query.

Comment: Do you have a table with all the ‘intervals’ for which you want to aggregate your ‘year’s worth of data?

Comment: Are you looking to aggregate over completely arbitrary ranges, or like the one example you give are you looking to do 24 hour window just starting at an arbitrary time of day?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @fromDt DATETIME = '06/11/2018 10:10:00';
DECLARE @toDt DATETIME = '06/12/2018 10:10:00';

SELECT SUM(IIF([Datetime] BETWEEN @fromDt AND @toDt, [PL], 0)) OVER() AS [Sum]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: This is sqlserver specific SQL, it won’t work for netezza or any or the other databases in the ‘postgres’ family

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select sum(PL) 
  from my_table 
  where DateTime between '2018-06-11 10:10:00' and '2018-06-12 10:10:00';
```

Comment: I have a year worth of data, cannot hard code it. Thanks though

Comment: Do you have a table with all the ‘intervals’ for which you want to aggregate your ‘year’s worth of data?